# How to use jQuery to select XML nodes with unique text content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm attempting to pull a list of unique text entries from an XML document "the jQuery way" and am hitting a wall.

From this XML:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <categories>
      <cat>Category 1</cat>
      <cat>Category 2</cat>
    </categories>
  </item>
  <item>
     <categories>
      <cat>Category 2</cat>
      <cat>Category 3</cat>
  </item>
 </items>
```

I'd like to generate a select list like:

```
<select>
 <option>Category 1</option>
 <option>Category 2</option>
 <option>Category 3</option>
</select>
```

So far all of my attempts produce a duplicate "Category 2" option node.  I attempted to make use of the $.unique() method, but the results make me think it's only comparing the node name, not the text content.  Here is my latest hackery that does not work:

```
var filters = $("cat",xmldoc);
filters = $.unique(filters);
$(filters).each(function()
{
    $("select").append("<option>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
});
```

I can think of a number of standard javascript tricks to make this happen, but am hoping there's a nice, elegant jQuery way to pull this off.

Any tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `cat` elements are not duplicates just because they have the same text content. They're still elements with their own, different identity, and consequently `unique` will not remove them.

You'll have to read the text contents into an array instead, and then remove duplicates from the Array-of-String.

Unfortunately, you also can't use `unique` afterwards on the Array-of-String, because it only supports DOM element items.

I'd just do the dupe removal when building the list:

```
var cats= [];
$('cat', xmldoc).each(function() {
    var text= $(this).text();
    if ($.inArray(text, cats)===-1)
        cats.push(text);
});
```

Then add each option to the select:

```
$.each(cats, function() {
    $('select').append($('<option>').attr('val', this).attr('text', this));
});
```

The option text needs to be set using `attr` and *not* by passing in the whole element as HTML. When you make HTML from text, you have to HTML-escape any text strings you are injecting into the HTML, otherwise you'll have potential cross-site-scripting security holes.

Comment: That jives with what I had thought.  Thanks for the confirmation.... inArray() it will be. :)