# jQuery: filter/get/select unique content of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I have the following XML document which I'm calling into my website's DOM using AJAX:

```
<product>
    <title>DVR 4 CH</title>
    <category>DVR</category>
</product>
<product>
    <title>DVR 8 CH</title>
    <category>DVR</category>
</product>
<product>
    <title>Infrared PIR motion sensor</title>
    <category>Alarms</category>
</product>
<product>
    <title>Bullet Camera 1000 TVL</title>
    <category>Bullet Cameras</category>
</product>
```

**How can I filter/get/select an array of `<category>` elements with unique HTML *content*?**. If you check back the code, you'll see there're four `<category>` elements: 2 x DVR, 1 x Alarms, 1 x Bullet Cameras.

I want to get only `<category>DVR</category>`, `<category>Alarms</category>`, and `<category>Bullet Cameras</category>` *(filtering the DVR category that was repeated)*.

jQuery has the [$.uniqueSort](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.uniqueSort/) function, which filters out duplicate **DOM elements**.

I needn't that. I need to filter those which have their inner HTML content unique/different. Here's the code I'm using (plus the AJAX), which displays in the console the four elements including the duplicated:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "../../../resources/xml/lista-de-precios/common/prices_database.xml",
    dataType: 'xml',
    cache: 'false',
    method: 'GET',
    async: 'true'
});
request.done(function() {
    getAndUseCategoriesAndLinks(request);
});

function getAndUseCategoriesAndLinks(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML,
        xml = $( xmlDoc ),
        category = xml.find("category");

    var each_element_new = $( category ).each(function() {
        console.log( $( this ).text() );
        $("ul.categories-list").append('<li><a href="#">' + $(this).text() + '</a></li>');
    });
}
```

Comment: you could have a callback fn for `$().filter()`?

Comment: have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232458/how-to-use-jquery-to-select-xml-nodes-with-unique-text-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of text string and remove duplicates, then you can easily append them.

```js
var responseXML = "<product> <title>DVR 4 CH</title> <category>DVR</category></product><product> <title>DVR 8 CH</title><category>DVR</category></product><product>    <title>Infrared PIR motion sensor</title><category>Alarms</category></product><product><title>Bullet Camera 1000 TVL</title><category>Bullet Cameras</category></product>";

var xmlDoc = responseXML,
  xml = $(xmlDoc),
  category = xml.find("category").map(function() {
    return this.textContent;
  });

unique(category).forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
  $("ul.categories-list").append('<li><a href="#">' + element + '</a></li>');
});

function unique(list) {
  var result = [];
  $.each(list, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
  });
  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly as expected. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of the *unique* categories like this from the XML:

```
[
  "DVR",
  "Alarms",
  "Bullet Cameras"
]
```

creating a *set* out of the *filtered* categories and inserting as a list in the HTML - see demo below:

```js
var xml = `<product>
    <title>DVR 4 CH</title>
    <category>DVR</category>
  </product>
  <product>
    <title>DVR 8 CH</title>
    <category>DVR</category>
  </product>
  <product>
    <title>Infrared PIR motion sensor</title>
    <category>Alarms</category>
  </product>
  <product>
    <title>Bullet Camera 1000 TVL</title>
    <category>Bullet Cameras</category>
  </product>`;

var list = [...(new Set(
  // get array of categories
  $(xml).find('category').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get()
))];

list.forEach(function(e) {
   $('.wrapper').append('<li>'+ e + '</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="wrapper"></ul>
```

Comment: Would I replace the ellipsis (...) in the variable list with the array like so: `var list = ["DVR", "Alarms", "Bullet Cameras", (new Set(` or just leave it like that?

Comment: `...` is the [*spread operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) - see the [*relations with arrays* section here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)